# Identify name of sampling / simulation strategy

Tags: bayesian, sampling, simulation

From what I've learned, it seems like in order to simulate draws from a distribution $X \sim p(X)$ one can take advantage of the fact that $p(X) = \int p(X, z)p(z)dz$ and use the following strategy:

1. Simulate a draw $z_i$ from $p(Z)$
2. Simulate a draw $x_i$ from $p(X|z_i)$

Then a histogram of the $x_i$'s will approximate $p(X)$.

I never understood why this sampling strategy works. It seems similar to Gibb's sampling except that we're simulating a draw from $p(Z)$ instead of $p(Z|x_{i-1})$. My question is if the sampling strategy has a name and if there is a proof that it works?

Comment: $p(X,Z) = p(X|Z)p(Z)$. This is just sampling from the joint distribution. (and using it  to estimate the marginal distribution $p(X)$ )

Comment: @J.Delaney I'm probably missing something but as I see it, that is just a formula for obtaining the joint probability, not to obtain a sample from the joint distribution? Why is it that if we sample from $p(Z)$ and then use this sample to obtain a sample from $p(X|Z)$ we get, in total, a sample from the joint distribution?

Comment: it follows pretty much from the definition of what a *conditional* distribution is (the distribution of $X$ given a certain value of $Z$). Maybe trying to work out the details of some simple example will help you understand it further